# Import fritzapi (node package) into Ionic project

Tags: ionic4, node-modules

I am currently trying to use [this](https://github.com/andig/fritzapi) API in my Ionic project, but man, I have no clue on how to do it. I tried figuring it out using things like [this](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/correct-way-to-add-3rd-party-libraries-js-or-npm/100897/6), but I always get errors on `ionic server`:

```
    101 unchanged chunks
[ng] chunk {home-home-module} home-home-module.js, home-home-module.js.map (home-home-module) 3.07 MB  [rendered]
[ng]
[ng] ERROR in ./node_modules/request/lib/har.js
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'D:\Programmierung\Workspaces\Ionic\HomeAutomation\node_modules\request\lib'
[ng] ERROR in ./node_modules/forever-agent/index.js
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in 'D:\Programmierung\Workspaces\Ionic\HomeAutomation\node_modules\forever-agent'
[ng] ERROR in ./node_modules/tough-cookie/lib/cookie.js
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in 'D:\Programmierung\Workspaces\Ionic\HomeAutomation\node_modules\tough-cookie\lib'
[ng] ERROR in ./node_modules/tunnel-agent/index.js
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in 'D:\Programmierung\Workspaces\Ionic\HomeAutomation\node_modules\tunnel-agent'
[ng] ERROR in ./node_modules/forever-agent/index.js
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tls' in 'D:\Programmierung\Workspaces\Ionic\HomeAutomation\node_modules\forever-agent'
[ng] ERROR in ./node_modules/tunnel-agent/index.js
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tls' in 'D:\Programmierung\Workspaces\Ionic\HomeAutomation\node_modules\tunnel-agent'
[ng] Time: 2321ms
[ng] i ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.
```

I'm super new to webdev and Ionic in general, so I don't know if this is even possible, but I feel like it should be. Above error is a result of the following code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import * as fritzapi from 'fritzapi';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor() { 
    fritzapi.getSessionID("removedforstack", "removedforstack").then(function(sid) {
      console.log(sid);
  });
  }

}
```

Thanks in advance to everyone who's trying to help <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect this isn't possible. I think that you are trying to use something that's expected to be run on the local network in a node environment.

I did a search and found this article:

https://www.amadousall.com/angular-cli-module-not-found-error-cant-resolve/

Which say they used to do this:

> supply an empty module when fs, crypto, tls and net were requested.

Which doesn't make sense really out of context but I couldn't find a simple bit to quote, take a look at the article.

Ultimately the angular team says:

> Browser code should not rely on things that are not available in browser environments.

I'm assuming that the library needs to use these things to connect to the local network and interact with your home automation.

If i'm wrong then the article does have a way to supply an empty file instead of those modules, so if the code has alternate modes then it could work, but it doesn't seem likely to me off the top of my head.

Comment: So I would've to set this up on a node server (save the info in a DB or something) and let the app request the info from said server/db?

Comment: Yeah I think so from what I'm seeing.

Comment: Thanks for marking it as the answer. It might seem silly but I would appreciate it if you could upvote the answer as well. Otherwise, for some reason, it doesn't count toward my Ionic4 tag badge that I'm trying to get. :)